# Looping to return value within dictionary in dictionary/list nest - must be integer or slices not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am creating a function to return the breed of a cat using the following list inside a dictionary and I keep receiving `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when trying to loop through the list within the value of `"pets"`:

```
cc_pet_shop = {
            "pets": [
                {
                    "name": "Sir Percy",
                    "pet_type": "cat",
                    "breed": "British Shorthair",
                    "price": 500
                },
                {
                    "name": "King Bagdemagus",
                    "pet_type": "cat",
                    "breed": "British Shorthair",
                    "price": 500
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sir Lancelot",
                    "pet_type": "dog",
                    "breed": "Pomsky",
                    "price": 1000,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Arthur",
                    "pet_type": "dog",
                    "breed": "Husky",
                    "price": 900,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tristan",
                    "pet_type": "cat",
                    "breed": "Basset Hound",
                    "price": 800,
                },
                {
                    "name": "Merlin",
                    "pet_type": "cat",
                    "breed": "Egyptian Mau",
                    "price": 1500,
                }
            ]
}
```

I have tried this many different ways with no success. I am tasked with writing the function based off of the test case. I believe the solution may need a count/counter to pass the test (see test case). I want to be able to index to any position within the list to find the cat breed hence the loop. `cc_pet_shop` containing the dictionary info will be passed to the function hence the argument in the function definition is `input_dict_of_list`.

my solution within the function body so far is as follows:

```
def get_pets_by_breed(input_dict_of_list, pet):
    for pet in cc_pet_shop:
       return input_dict_of_list["pets"][pet]["breed"]
```

I believe I have the correct syntax for the value of the breed key with

```
cc_pet_shop["pets"][pet]["breed"]
```

I need to satisfy a unit test case so my function required two arguments, the

```
input_dict_of_list
```

which represents cc_pet_shop as well as

```
pet
```

which represents any index position within the list holding a breed key value pair.

If it provided further clarity, this is the format of the test case my code is being checked against:

```
def test_all_pets_by_breed__found(self):
        pets = get_pets_by_breed(self.cc_pet_shop, "British Shorthair")
        self.assertEqual(2, len(pets))
```

Comment: When you do `for pet in cc_pet_shop:`, what values are you expecting `pet` to have? When you subsequently do `input_dict_of_list["pets"][pet]["breed"]`, what do you expect the type of `input_dict_of_list["pets"]` to be? Is `pet` a valid index for that? Separately: what do you expect to accomplish by `return`ing this value from inside a for loop? You do understand that you can only return once per call, yes?

Comment: It comes across that you are missing fundamentals, specifically how `for` loops work in Python. You would be better served by reviewing a tutorial rather than asking your question here. You may find e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html helpful.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your suggestion. I have been working on this problem for hours and am basically burned out at this point. I am reading fundamentals and have come to stack overflow as a final resort so would appreciate any solution so that I can consolidate my understanding.

In plain english, my function should return the value of breed when it is called. It should do this for any of the dictionaries stored within the list, which is the value of the "pets" key.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what the requirement is. Can you give an example of what the provided value for `pet` might be, and what the resulting output should be, and show the reasoning?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel apologies, the requirement is to have a function which can access the list containing breeds of cat and it will return the breed stored in the breed key value pair when called. It is tested against the test case above (which is not to be modified so can be considered "correct"). The function definition must satisfy the unit test case which appears to have two arguments in the assertEqual() method in order to pass the test and prove that the function can return the breed of cat. Hope this is somewhat clearer.

Comment: Okay, so you should start by writing out, in plain English words, the intended logic of the program, step by step. Be sure to explain the reasoning: in particular,  *why* you are looping and what you want to accomplish each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - I love that you presented this with a test for correctness. Awesome.

Secondly, you are accessing a list of dicts inside a list - which can be a tad confusing. Assuming that neither the test function nor the structure of `cc_pet_shop` can be changed, and also taking some liberties with how I present this based on your apparent use of `unittest`, this is a working solution:

```py
import unittest

def get_pets_by_breed(pet_dict, breed):
    results = []
    for pet in pet_dict['pets']:
        if pet['breed'] == breed:
            results.append(pet)
    return results

class LegiScanTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.cc_pet_shop = {"pets": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Sir Percy",
                                    "pet_type": "cat",
                                    "breed": "British Shorthair",
                                    "price": 500
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "King Bagdemagus",
                                    "pet_type": "cat",
                                    "breed": "British Shorthair",
                                    "price": 500
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Sir Lancelot",
                                    "pet_type": "dog",
                                    "breed": "Pomsky",
                                    "price": 1000,
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Arthur",
                                    "pet_type": "dog",
                                    "breed": "Husky",
                                    "price": 900,
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Tristan",
                                    "pet_type": "cat",
                                    "breed": "Basset Hound",
                                    "price": 800,
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Merlin",
                                    "pet_type": "cat",
                                    "breed": "Egyptian Mau",
                                    "price": 1500,
                                }
                            ]
            }
    
    def test_all_pets_by_breed__found(self):
        pets = get_pets_by_breed(self.cc_pet_shop, 'British Shorthair')
        self.assertEqual(2, len(pets))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here's an alternate implementation of your function that accomplishes the same thing in a single line using a list comprehension:

```py
def get_pets_by_breed_alt(pet_dict, breed):
    return [pet for pet in pet_dict['pets'] if pet['breed'] == breed]
```

Answer (score 2):

`input_dict_of_list["pets"]` is a **list**. This list contains 6 items, which can be accessed as `input_dict_of_list["pets"][0]`, `input_dict_of_list["pets"][1]`, ..., `input_dict_of_list["pets"][5]`.

The names of the breeds can be accessed as `input_dict_of_list["pets"][0]['breed']`, `input_dict_of_list["pets"][1]['breed']`, ..., `input_dict_of_list["pets"][5]['breed']`.

Or you can iterate over the items in this list using a `for`-loop:

```py
for breed_dict in input_dict_of_list["pets"]:
  print(breed_dict['breed'])
```

Note: no need for `pet += 1` at the end of a `for`-loop in python. Python handles the iteration on its own.

### `get_pets_by_breed(cc_pet_shop, 'British Shorthair')`

Since we want to return a list, we can use a list comprehension instead of a `for`-loop:

```py
def get_pets_by_breed(cc_pet_shop, breed):
  return [d for d in cc_pet_shop['pets'] if d['breed'] == breed]

print(get_pets_by_breed(cc_pet_shop, "British Shorthair"))
# [
#  {'price': 500, 'breed': 'British Shorthair', 'name': 'Sir Percy', 'pet_type': 'cat'},
#  {'price': 500, 'breed': 'British Shorthair', 'name': 'King Bagdemagus', 'pet_type': 'cat'}
# ]
```

Comment: Hi, this solution appears to work when not defined inside a function and when given the cc_pet_shop dictionary/list. 

However, as shown in the test case my function requires two arguments to satisfy the test case and I am receiving the error:

    return input_dict_of_list(pet["breed"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

when placing it within the function I have described above. Could you possibly amend your solution to satisfy the test case I provided and defined within the function definition so that the unit test works with it? Thank you

Comment: @loco Done. I added function `get_pets_by_breed`.